# if jQuery statement | empty text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so i have been literally trying to figure this out for the past hour, its such a simple thing that i never have a problem with. So the input 'username_input' has a jQuery if state that is

```
if($('#username_input').val() == 0) {
    alert('Empty');
} else {
    alert('Not empty');
}
```

After that it moves onto the 'password_input' if statement which is the same thing, but it keeps alerting 'empty'. Why?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Awflicks </title>
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="body_div">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div id="username_div"> Username:  <input type="text" name="username" id="username_input"> </div>
                <div id="password_div"> Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password_input"> </div>
                <div id="retype_password_div"> Retype password: <input type="password" name="retype_password" id="retype_password_input"> </div>
                <div type="submit" id="submit_button"> Create Account </div>
            </form>
        </div>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                var $username = $('#username_input').val();
                var $password1 = $('#password_input').val();
                var $password2 = $('#retype_password_input').val();

                    function create_account() {
                        if($username == 0) {
                            alert('empty');
                        } else {
                            alert('not empty')
                        }
                    }

                $('#submit_button').click(function() {
                    create_account();
                    document.forms[0].submit();
                })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `value == 0` is rather awkward. You're not checking whether it's zero, but whether it's empty. Because of JavaScript truthiness, you could instead say `if (value)`

Answer (score 1):

Because the variable with the value does not get updated when the value changes. It is the value when it is read. You need to read the value when you want it or set the variable onchange.

Also not sure how the value would be zero since there is no value set. Shouldn't you be checking the length? And you are going to want to return a Boolean from your validation function so you know to cancel the form submission.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use this without defining variables

```
if(!$('#username_input').val()) // or if(!$('#password_input').val()) for password input
{
   alert('empty');
} else {
   alert('not empty')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor as follows to ensure that $username will only store the value once an input has been committed (e.g. once submit has been pressed)

```
function create_account() {
   var $username = $('#username_input').val();
   var $password1 = $('#password_input').val();
   var $password2 = $('#retype_password_input').val();
   if($username == 0) {
      alert('empty');
   } else {
      alert('not empty')
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you make the changes suggested by the other answers, you are going to have an issue with your form always getting submitted even when the alert shows "Empty". In fact, it will get submitted twice when the alert shows "Not empty". That is because your "submit_button" has `type="submit"` so it submits the form. You could change to `type="button"`, but my preference is to bind the handler to the form's submit-event, instead of the button's click-event.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from getting submitted.

    var username = $('#username_input').val();
    var password1 = $('#password_input').val();
    var password2 = $('#retype_password_input').val();

    var isValid = true;

    if (username == '') {
        alert('Empty');
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (isValid) {
        this.submit(); // Now submit the form.
    }
});
```